# How to ListThings AWS IOT in android

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

This is the code snippet:

```
private  AWSIotClient awsIotClient;

 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 if (sAWSCredentials == null) {
            sAWSCredentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
        }

        awsIotClient = new AWSIotClient(sAWSCredentials);
      //  awsIotClient.setEndpoint(iotDataEndpoint);
        Region region = Region.getRegion(MY_REGION);
        awsIotClient.setRegion(region);

getThings() ;

}

 public void getThings() {
          GetThingsList getThingsList = new GetThingsList();
        getThingsList.execute();

}
     private  class GetThingsList extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, AsyncTaskResult<String>> {
    @Override
    protected AsyncTaskResult<String> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        try {
            ListThingsRequest thingList = new ListThingsRequest();
            thingList.withAttributeName("type");
            awsIotClient.setEndpoint(CUSTOMER_SPECIFIC_ENDPOINT);
            ListThingsResult thingsResult = awsIotClient.listThings(thingList);
            Log.v(TAG, "listThings " + thingsResult);
            return new AsyncTaskResult<String>(thingsResult.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("E", "getThingTask", e);
            return new AsyncTaskResult<String>(e);
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(AsyncTaskResult<String> result) {
        if (result.getError() == null) {
            Log.i(GetShadowTask.class.getCanonicalName(), result.getResult());
        } else {
            Log.e(GetShadowTask.class.getCanonicalName(), "getThingTask", result.getError());
        }
    }
}
```

Still the list of the things is coming empty. Is there any way to get the list things? Used AWSIoTClient listThings method, as shown in the code snippet. It will be helpful if anyone can provide with sample code.

Comment: Can you fix the code in your question to show your actual code? Right now you are showing code in your question that would't be able to compile, specifically this line: `return );`

Comment: @MarkB: Please check my code I have updated it.I am getting the response as {things: [],}. Please help me to ListThings

Comment: @MarkB: I am getting com.amazonaws.services.iot.model.ResourceNotFoundException: Not Found (Service: AWSIot; Status Code: 404; Error Code: ResourceNotFoundException;

Comment: @MarkB: I am getting 404 error for this HTTP request: https://endpoint.iot.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/things?attributeName=key&attributeValue=value

Comment: Are your endpoint and the region correct, also do you have the appropriate permissions to get the things?

Comment: @abhinayg Can you verify the endpoint, region and the credentials are all correct and set with the appropriate roles and permissions? Is your cognito identity pool-id belong to the right region you are using?